# Pass data from jquery to popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup, jquery-ui-dialog

I have code like this:

```
<img src='../imagesManageDebitur/edit.png' onclick='updateData(<?php echo $fasilitasInput[$rowInput]->CASHLOAN_ID; ?>)'/>
```

And i have javascript like this:

```
function updateData(data){
    alert(data);
    dialog.dialog("open");
}

dialog = $( "#getform" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true
});
```

And i have form to popup:

```
<div id="getform" title="Create new user">
          <center><b><p class="validateTips">Edit Data</p></b></center>

          <form name="frm_data_nasabah20" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  method="post" action="<?php echo $page_action;?>">   
            <table width='100%'>
            <tr>
              <td height="20px"><label for="name">Nomor Rekening</label></td>
              <td height="20px">:</td>
              <td height="20px"><input required='required' type="text" name="NOMOR_REKENING" id="NOMOR_REKENING" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
              </td>
            </tr></table></form></div>
```

When i try to alert data, i get data with different id. I want to search data with query select, and pass it to the input value. How can i search it and pass it to the input form?

Comment: you mean you want to fetch data from database according to "id" you passed in "updateData" and insert into text input inside popup? if yes then you can use "ajax" in "updateData" to get it.

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma yes, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to achieve this:
Here your ajax should return a json like.

```
{"val1":"abc","val2":"def","val3":"xyz"}
```

& your function

```
function updateData(data){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { data: data }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#NOMOR_REKENING').val(result.val1);
        $('#NOMOR_REKENING1').val(result.val2);
        $('#NOMOR_REKENING2').val(result.val3);
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
}
```

Comment: how can i pass the value to NOMOR_REKENING value?

Comment: this is just for one element, what if i have more than one element to pass to form?